# Windows or components do not show up in Java Swing

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I am getting started with Java Swing using Eclipse on MacOS. I read some tutorials; however, I failed to reproduce the results: whenever I copy-paste a sample code, the result is different from what I am supposed to get.

For example, with [this](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javaswingtutorial/firstprograms/) I get the empty window, but not the buttons and other stuff.

Another example is code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/14673412/4189299: when I run it, I observe only this (instead of a button and two text fields):

[image]

Do I miss something or should I change some Eclipse settings?

Answer (score -1):

In the first example you should only get simple frame with no buttons at all. Just a frame with a title. Here is a  [Simple Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3SvK.png.).

On the other case in the second example I tried and example is fine. Maybe you should check that you copied all code?